# Jquery events response does not set style or js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I needed to hide and unhide a div tag with select2 select class with jquery

if i do so, the width of the select input becomes very small and cannot do anything

I need a solution to get the width of the input tag as usual after the jquery event happens

this is my HTML I have added a hidden class on the second row - id -> countrydiv. I needed it to remove and add hidden class with onchange event

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
        <h5 class="card-title">Worldwide</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-check form-switch ml-2">
            <input class="form-check-input boot-switch" type="checkbox" id="countrycheckbox" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 text-left">
        <h5 class="card-title">Select Country</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row hidden" id="countrydiv">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <form action="{{ url('/search') }}" method="get">
            <div class="input-group text-left">                                                
                <Select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id="searchCountry"> 
                    <option value="" >Select Country</option>
                    @foreach ($data['countries'] as $countries)
                        <option value="{{ $countries->id }}" @if(old('search-artist')==$countries->id) selected @else @endif>{{ $countries->country }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </Select>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my jquery

```
$('#countrycheckbox').on('change',function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('#countrydiv').removeClass('hidden');
    }else{
        $('#countrydiv').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Please help me with a solution as i needed the secound image as the output after the event onchange

Comment: Try wrapping you code inside a `($document).ready(function(){ [YOUR CODE HERE] })`... And also look at the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) because maybe you have some error somewhere. -- From what is posted, there nothing wrong and that script should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class named hidden as the following example:

```js
$('#countrycheckbox').on('change',function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('#countrydiv').addClass('hidden');
    }else{
        $('#countrydiv').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
        <h5 class="card-title">Worldwide</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-check form-switch ml-2">
            <input class="form-check-input boot-switch" type="checkbox" id="countrycheckbox" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 text-left">
        <h5 class="card-title">Select Country</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row " id="countrydiv">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <form action="{{ url('/search') }}" method="get">
            <div class="input-group text-left">                                                
                <Select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id="searchCountry"> 
                    <option value="" >Select Country</option>
                    @foreach ($data['countries'] as $countries)
                        <option value="{{ $countries->id }}" @if(old('search-artist')==$countries->id) selected @else @endif>{{ $countries->country }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </Select>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah i have already added i needed to removeclass when checked.. at that time initially there should be no input tag so i hav added a hidden class as mentioned above in the code